# MySQL join/inner join 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas.

- Users, en las que obtengo las siguientes columnas (username).
- Submissions, obtengo las columnas (id, title, thumbnail y rate). También tiene la columna user_id para saber que usuario hizo la subida.
- Favorites, obtengo las 3 columnas (date, id_submission, id_user)

La cuestión es que estoy viendo el perfil de un usuario y obtengo su ID, y me gustaría mostrar las submissions las cuales ha marcado como favoritas. Más o menos funciona, pero no del todo bien.

Código SQL:
La variable `$user[0]["id"]` es la ID del usuario que estas viendo.

```
$query = "SELECT f.date, s.id, s.title, s.rate, s.thumbnail, u.username
FROM favorites AS f
INNER JOIN submissions AS s
    ON f.id_submission = s.id
INNER JOIN users AS u
    ON f.id_user = ".$user[0]["id"]."
ORDER BY f.date DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Con un usuario A he marcado como favorito una submission del usuario B. Pero cuando estoy viendo el perfil del usuario A, me muestra 2 veces la misma submission.

Algo pasa con la SQL pero no estoy muy seguro del qué. Siempre suelo hacer  consultas dentro de loops, pero estoy intentando mejorarlas e intentar hacerlas en una sola para mejorar el rendimiento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que es mejor que quites la condición de la inner y la pongas en un where:

```
$query = "SELECT f.date, s.id, s.title, s.rate, s.thumbnail, u.username
FROM favorites AS f
INNER JOIN submissions AS s
    ON f.id_submission = s.id
INNER JOIN users AS u
    ON f.id_user = u.id
WHERE f.id_user = ".$user[0]["id"]."
ORDER BY f.date DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: ¡Es verdad, como voy a restringir la búsqueda sin un WHERE! ¡Gracias!

Comment: De nada :) A todos se nos escapa algo.